# Python HTTP request with json data isn't getting php response with json data

Tags: php, python, http, httprequest, httpresponse

I am trying to send a python http request with some json data (I will use this json data in a later case) to server. Server should give a response with some json data (using PHP). Unfortunately there is no any response even though request status code is 200. Any help please!

```
#request.py

import requests
import urllib3
import json
import os
import time
import sys

#http Request
url = 'http://localhost/response.php'
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json'}

while True:

    postMessage = '{"Info": {"ID": 1, "IP": "192.168.1.1"}}'
    response = requests.post(url, json=postMessage, headers=headers)
    #trying to decode the response
    try:
        decodedresponse = json.loads(response.text) 
        print(decodedresponse)

    except(ValueError, KeyError, TypeError):
        print("some Error")

#always getting the above print statement!

    break
```

```
#response.php


<?php

if(!empty($_POST['json'])){
  $data = [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ];  
  header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');
  echo json_encode($data);

}
 ?>
```

Comment: `postMessage = {"Info": {"ID": 1, "IP": "192.168.1.1"}}`

Comment: @OlvinRoght still same problem

Comment: Cause you're trying to find post field `json` which doesn't exist.

Comment: `$data = file_get_contents("php://input");` and then `echo json_decode($data);`

Comment: @OlvinRoght I am getting the same error!

Comment: @OlvinRoght any more suggestion please. I almost gave up !!!

Comment: I've write you my suggestion. Read all input and decode json. It doesn't work?

Comment: i tried it. It didn't work. it seems like POST input is empty. so when I tried to read it inside if statement using file_get_contents("php://input") , nothing happened, else statement got executed.

Comment: @OlvinRoght I need ID and IP values in later cases to  collect some data from Database. !!!

Comment: Are you kidding me? I've provided you solution, you can't apply it and complain that I haven't done all work for you?

Comment: `$data = file_get_contents("php://input"); `    It didn't work. I said it already. Sorry for the misunderstanding!

Comment: Cause you've put it into if statement which will never be true.

Comment: @OlvinRoght Oh man. thank you so much. it worked. But a slight change. not  `echo json_decode($data);` but `echo json_encode($data); `

Comment: I've posted my answer, you can select it if it helped you to solve problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove quotes on assignment of `postMessage` in your:

```
postMessage = {"Info": {"ID": 1, "IP": "192.168.1.1"}}
```

And change your php code to:

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your $_POST structure.

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['Info'])){
   $data = [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ];  
   echo json_encode($data);
 }
 else{
     echo json_encode(ison_decode($_POST, TRUE));
 }
```

Comment: I made mistake try now w/o json_encode because post data is json and we don't need json_encode.

Comment: the above code works. But i realized that only else statement is executing. !!! don't know why

Comment: beacouse you don't have or empty $_POST['json']... once again - check your post data structure. I made changes to my answer check and try again.

Comment: no way, if statement is not working.  and  echo $_POST does nothing. so output is same (JSON Error). The problem is empty $_POST['json'] . Tried your new code as well.  Given some data to else like $dataElse = [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ];
  echo json_encode($dataElse); it worked

Comment: I made changes try now.

Comment: no way. it is not working.. any thank you so much for the efforts.